# Magento : Get product categories with ORDER BY

Tags: php, magento

I'm currently retrieving a list of categories the current product is linked to on the product view.phtml page with the following:

```
$cats = $_product->getCategoryIds();
```

Then looping them out on the page like so:

```
foreach($cats as $category_id)
{
  $_cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
  // do stuff
}
```

How can I retrieve this list ordered by the category name?

Alternatively I've tried the following, but when I make use of the $catCollection in the foreach statement I'm given a 404 error?

```
$catIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$catCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')  
->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $catIds)
->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC')
->addIsActiveFilter();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unable to test this at the moment, but this should work for you:

Do this instead of your foreach to get them in order.

```
$catIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$catCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $catIds))
    ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
foreach($catCollection as $cat){
    echo $cat->getName(), "<br>";
}
```

Comment: this isnt having an affect at the moment.